# RouteAttribute broke my Default route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

If I apply **[Route(Name = "WhatEver")]** to action, which I use as Default site route, I get HTTP 404 when accesing site root.

For example:

- Create new sample MVC project.
- Add attributes routing:

  ```
  // file: App_Start/RouteConfig.cs
  public class RouteConfig
  {
      public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
      {
          routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
          routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); // Add this line
          routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Default",
              url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
      }
  }
  ```
- Add routing attributes

  ```
  [RoutePrefix("Zome")]
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
      [Route(Name = "Zndex")]
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
          return View();
      }
      ...
  }
  ```

And now, when you start your project for debuging, you will have HTTP Error 404. How should I use attribute routing with default route mapping?

Comment: What is the purpose behind using `[Route(Name = "Zndex")]` attribute for `Index` action? `[domain]/Zome` will automatically refer to `[domain]/Zome/Index`, using `RouteAttribute` may require `[domain]/Zome/Zndex` to reach `Index` action.

Comment: I think route names are not used in route matching, so `[domain]/Zome/Zndex` points to nowhere. I need a name for route on Index action, because I want to use Url helper with route names like this: `<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Zndex")">Zndex page</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For default route using attribute routing with route prefix you need to set the route template as an empty string. You can also override the site root using `~/` if the controller already has a route prefix.

```
[RoutePrefix("Zome")]
public class HomeController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("", Name = "Zndex")]      //Matches GET /Zome
    [Route("Zndex")]                 //Matches GET /Zome/Zndex
    [Route("~/", Name = "default")]  //Matches GET /  <-- site root
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }
    //...
}
```

That said, when using attribute routing on a controller it no longer matches convention-based routes. The controller is either all attribute-based or all convention-based that do not mix.

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: can you please point me to any doc that actually said, that I can use only attribute routing, or convention routing on my controller, but not both. You reference link actually saids (3 times) that I CAN use them both in the same project (but not on the same controller?) thx anyway

Comment: @vasily.sib It has to do with the order of route registration. because attribute routes are checked before convention-based routes, as soon as a controller uses route attribute, it will never reach the convention based routes. Even if there was no match to the attribute route. You will get the not found 404 error.

Comment: Got it. Adding `[Route("~/", Name = "Zefault")]` attribute to Index action do the trick. However, I actually **can** mix "attribute-routing" and "convention-routing" within the same controller, **but not** on the same action. In my sample app, I can access `/Home/About` action, but `/Home/Index` will return 404. Is this documented anywhere in the internets? Huge thanks to mr. @nkosi for pointing my on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you start your site there is a default route set in the route.config file in the App_Start folder. It looks something like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

If you no longer have an "index" action in your home controller the site tries in vain to fin that as the home page and will return a 404. You can update your route.config file to reference the new home page.