# Routing with multiple parameters (String, DateTime) is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I have three Action Result methods with same name and all of these are [httpPost] types. i use attribute routing to bound these methods when i add attribute routing non of these method get invoked but when i remove routing attribute from any one of these method, then only that method get invoked. please guide me where i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

First method

```
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("Home/PrintFileMovement/{option}/{SearchBox}")]
    public ActionResult PrintFileMovement(string option, string SearchBox)
    {
        FileMovementManagementSystem.FileViewModel.FileViewModel fvm = new FileMovementManagementSystem.FileViewModel.FileViewModel();
        List<File_Movement> fileMovementModel;


        if (option == "DiaryNo")
        {
            //FileMovementManagementSystem.FileViewModel.FileViewModel fvm = new FileMovementManagementSystem.FileViewModel.FileViewModel();
            fileMovementModel = fvm.SearchFileByDiaryNo(SearchBox);
            return View(fileMovementModel);
        }
        else if (option == "Subject")
        {
           // FileMovementManagementSystem.FileViewModel.FileViewModel fvm = new FileMovementManagementSystem.FileViewModel.FileViewModel();
            fileMovementModel = fvm.SearchFileBySubject(SearchBox);
            return View(fileMovementModel);
        }

        fileMovementModel = fvm.GetFileMovement();
        return View(fileMovementModel);
    }
```

Second method which is working fine without routing attributes

```
   [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   [Route("Home/PrintFileMovement/{option}/{Date:datetime}")]

    public ActionResult PrintFileMovement(string option, DateTime? Date)
    {

        FileMovementManagementSystem.FileViewModel.FileViewModel fvm = new FileMovementManagementSystem.FileViewModel.FileViewModel();
        List<File_Movement> fileMovementModel;
        if (option == "ReceiveDate")
        {

             fileMovementModel = fvm.SearchFileByReceiveDate(Date.Value);
             return View(fileMovementModel);
        }

            fileMovementModel = fvm.GetFileMovement();
            return View(fileMovementModel);
    }
```

And here is 3rd method

```
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("Home/PrintFileMovement/{MyDate:datetime}")]
    public ActionResult PrintFileMovement(DateTime? MyDate)
    {
        FileMovementManagementSystem.FileViewModel.FileViewModel fvm = new FileMovementManagementSystem.FileViewModel.FileViewModel();
        List<File_Movement> fileMovementModel = fvm.SearchFileByReceiveDate(MyDate.Value);
        return View(fileMovementModel);

    }
```

RouteConfig

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );



    }
```

Comment: I have [some simular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210685/routeattribute-broke-my-default-route) some time ago. Maybe this will help.

Comment: It will be helpfull if you add you routing setup (`RouteConfig.cs`) and controller attributes

Comment: @vasily.sib please see my updated question code there i added routeconfig.cs code.

Comment: @vasily.sib please see my updated question code there i added routeconfig.cs code.

Comment: what about your controller attributes? Do you have some `[RoutePrefix("Home")]` over `public class HomeController : Controller` line?

Comment: @vasily.sib is that necessary to add Prefix?

Comment: no, but if you have it - we would like to know

Comment: no i did't added it

Answer (score 0):

You need enable  `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` in `RegisterRoutes`

and change `DateTime` to `DateTime?` in your parameter and use `MyDate.Value` in action.

Make sure name of input tag same with parameter name

```
public ActionResult PrintFileMovement(string option, DateTime? Date)

<input type="text" name="option" />
<input type="text" name="Date" />
```

Updated:

I have just tried to reproduce your case, because you use POST method, so you need remove `/{option}/{Date:datetime}` in Route, POST method did not send data via URL.

Change to this will work

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("Home/PrintFileMovement")]

public ActionResult PrintFileMovement(string option, DateTime? Date)
```

In cshtml file:

```
<form action="/Home/PrintFileMovement" method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @*<input type="text" name="option"/>*@
    <input type="text" name="Date"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You mark as HttpPost and you need tool to POST data, or you want use GET method for all? or you can post your View cshtml

Comment: My previous comment was not correctly edited, but the question remains. Why do you think they need to change `DateTime` to `DateTime?` in action parameters?

Comment: @HienNguyen i want to post my view cshtml.

Comment: @HienNguyen when i change to this [Route("Home/PrintFileMovement")] then i get resource not found error message

Comment: I added cshtml content

Comment: That is all code, I add action in  public class HomeController : Controller, and add form to Index.cshtml file